Is the load part of a read-modify-write operation of atomic object guaranteed to read the last value in modification order compared to load operation?
Consider this example:
std::atomic<int> v = {0};

// thread 1:
for(int i = 0; i<999999;i++)
   v.load(memory_order::seq_cst);  // #1

v.exchange(2,memory_order::seq_cst);  // #2

//thread 2:
  v.store(1,memory_order::seq_cst);  // #3

Assuming the modification order of v is {0, 1} where 0 is written by the initialization of v and 1 is stored by #3 in thread 2 and both #1 and #2 does not happen before #3. According to [intro.races] p14 ~ p18:

The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, is the value stored by some unspecified side effect A that modifies M, where B does not happen before A.


If an operation A that modifies an atomic object M happens before an operation B that modifies M, then A is earlier than B in the modification order of M.


If a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, and A takes its value from a side effect X on M, then the value computed by B is either the value stored by X or the value stored by a side effect Y on M, where Y follows X in the modification order of M.


If a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before an operation B that modifies M, then A takes its value from a side effect X on M, where X precedes B in the modification order of M.


If a side effect X on an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, then the evaluation B takes its value from X or from a side effect Y that follows X in the modification order of M.

the load operation at #1 is permitted to always read 0 until the end of the loop, it also can be 1. However, the load part of #2 must read 1 that is written by #3 as per [atomics.order] p10

Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation.

In this case, if #1 always reads 0 in its loop, it also does not violate the single total:
#1 is sequenced before #2, which also means #1 strongly happens before #2, so, in the single total order, #1 precedes #2, since #1 reads 0 and 0 precedes 1(produced by #3) in the modification order of v, according to [atomics.order] p3

An atomic operation A on some atomic object M is coherence-ordered before another atomic operation B on M if


A is a modification, and B reads the value stored by A, or
[...]
A and B are not the same atomic read-modify-write operation, and there exists an atomic modification X of M such that A reads the value stored by X and X precedes B in the modification order of M, or



#1 is coherence-ordered before #3, hence, #1 precedes #3 in the single total order. Finally, since #2 reads the value written by #3, #3 is coherence-ordered before #2, hence #3 precedes #2 in the single total order. which all three requirements


#1 precedes #2
#1 precedes #3
#3 precedes #2


can form a valid single total {#1, #3, #2}
Hence, with the pre-conditions, #1 can always load 0, and #2 must read the value 1. Is this a possible output?

As far as I can see, any of three things can happen: (A) all #1 loads read 0 and #2 also reads 0; (B) all #1 loads read 0 and #2 reads 1; (C) at least one of the #1 loads read 1, and so do all subsequent #1 as well as #2.  Each case puts #3 somewhere different in the total order, but all are consistent with #1 and #2 not happening before #3.  (Your assumption that the modification order of v is {0,1} is not quite possible because the value 2 must also be included; it can either be {0,1,2} or {0,2,1}.)

Indeed, regardless of the program's behavior, there is no case in which we could possibly conclude that either #1 or #2 happens before #3, as thread 2 doesn't contain any operation that could provide synchronization in that direction.    So your assumption (#1 and #2 don't happen before #3) doesn't restrict the program's behavior in any way.

@NateEldredge Given the assumption that the modification order is {0,1}, <<all #1 loads read 0 and #2 also reads 0>> why can#2 load 0?

@NateEldredge Please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79118090/does-the-standard-impose-more-requirement-on-the-load-part-of-rmw-than-a-pure-lo, I think it expresses clearer than this question.

I think you're overthinking it.

Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation.

This just says that RMWs are invidivisable, i.e. no writes can be inserted between the read part and the write part. (In other words, they say that the "write" part of RMW appears in the modification order right after the value that was read by the "read" part, that's all).
This doesn't say that RMWs are any less prone to reading stale values than non-RMW reads. (Maybe that's what happens in practice on some platforms, but that's above my paygrade and isn't the point.)
This presumed difference doesn't affect how you analyze the programs anyway. If all #1s returned 0, and #2 suddenly returned 1, is it because, #1 was reading a "stale" value, or because #3 happened to happen exactly between the last #1 and #2? You can't tell, and it doesn't matter.
Also operations on v have to be consistent with the global seq-cst order, but that doesn't tell you much. (If all #1s returned 0 and #2 returned 1, then #3 lands between the latest #1 and #2. If some #1 returns 1, then #3 is right before that, etc.)

[assume that] both #1 and #2 does not happen before #3

They can't happen-before #3 in the first place, I believe (for A to happen-before B in a different thread, there has to be a synchronizes-with relationship, so either B must be a read, or must have a preceding read in the same thread). At best you can say they're coherence-ordered-before, or that #2 precedes #3 in the modification order of v.
In general, I'd start my assumptions with what value each load returns, and deduce the various "...-before" orderings from there, not the other way around.

This just sounds like they want to guarantee that RMWs are invidivisable, i.e. no writes can be inserted between the read part and the write part. As said in the question, I gave the assumption that the modification is {0, 1}, when the RMW wrote it side effect to the modification order, its read value must be the latest one before its written value, that is 1, isn't it?

@xmh0511 Yes, I don't think I said otherwise.

What I was asking is that, even though we know there are already two side effects {s0, s1} in the modification order of an atomic object, the load operation can read the stale value(s0) however an RMW operation must read the latest value before its written side effect since its write operation will make the modification order be {s0, s1, s2}, s1 must be the value the RMW reads.

@xmh0511 Yeah, this is what you said in the question. I think I addressed this in the answer. Again: 1. I don't think "last" means what you think it does. They just mean that the write part of RMW appears in the modification order right after the value that was read by the read part, that's all. They aren't saying that RMWs are less prone to reading stale values. And 2. this assumption has no practical effect anyway, it doesn't help you reason about the program behavior. If all #1s return 0 and #2 returns 1, ...

...it doesn't matter if this was caused by #1 reading stale values or by #3 not happening until after the last `#1.

@xmh0511 Also notice how it says "last value ... written before the write", not just "last" in general.

However, saying the side effect produced by #3 was in the modification order does mean that #3 has happened. I just suppose a possible case is that the modification order is {0, 1} before the first load at #1 is evaluated and in this situation what values all #1 and #2 can read, I think #1 can always read 0 but #2 must read 1 due to the modification is {0, 1}, is this right?

@xmh0511 You can't consider the value returned by the most recent load and the "current modification order" in isolation. If the most recent load returned 0, then (as far as thread 1 is concerned) the "current" order is still {0}.

Or, another way to think about it is that there's no such thing as the "current" modification order in the first place. There's only the (timeless) modification order as it will be at the end of execution, and you can use the most recent load to judge where you (a specific thread) are in it currently.

"If the most recent load returned 0, then (for thread 1) the "current" order is still {0}" This is not true, even though the modification is {0,1,2,3}, that load operation can return 0 provided the modification operation of the subsequent side effect does not happen-before the load operation.

@xmh0511 Again, strictly speaking there's no such thing as the "current" order. You only know the value returned by the most recent order, and can use it to judge about where in the final (as it will be at the end of execution) modification order you currently are.

So, you mean, a modification order can only exist at the end of the program?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For this topic, I found two relevant questions where the answers agree that RMW operation read the "last value" in modification order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795126/does-exchange-or-compare-and-exchange-reads-last-value-in-modification-order
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43506604/11796722

@xmh0511 ...we've been over this, aren't we? :/ The links quote the same thing you do, and the quote says "last value ... before the write", not just "last" in general. The word "last" in this context means "immediately preceding X", not "most recent in time". The latter definition wouldn't make sense in multithreaded context in the first place, because there are multiple timelines, not just one, so you can't directly judge what is "latest" without some additional reservations.

If the write part of the RMW operation is the last value in the modification order, isn't the read value was the last value before the write? "last value" is mentioned in the standard, https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#18

@xmh0511 Sure, but the whole paragraph sounds non-normative ("should"...). What you're saying makes some sense in practice, and apparently that's why RMWs on x86 are always seq-cst. But I still believe that this isn't something the standard directly requires, and that e.g. there should be no difference between seq-cst loads and seq-cst RMWs in this regard.

But I still believe that this isn't something the standard directly requires. The standard does not require but permit. Thinking it in this way, given an abstract modification order {M0, M1, ..., Mn}, the pure loading operation is permitted to read any of them as long as that side effect is the candidate specified in [intro.races] p14 and does not violate other rules. For a successfully executed RMW operation, because its modification becomes Mn+1 in the modification order, hence its reading value must be Mn, it cannot be M0 ~ MN-1.

@xmh0511 Mhm, but as I already said, this mental model is equivalent to saying that all loads read the last value in the modification order, but threads can disagree on what the current modification order is. I'm not sure if it's correct to think that there's a shared "true" current modification order across threads that RMWs access, it doesn't seem to be directly required.

@xmh0511 and HolyBlackCat: On real-world systems, the C++ guarantees are provided by the hardware having coherent caches, so a store can't commit to cache until this core has exclusive ownership of it (all other copies invalidated).  So yes, there is a true modification order for each cache line.  C++'s formalism allows some things (in terms of orderings across separate variables) that I think are impossible on any normal hardware, even ones that allow IRIW reordering by making stores visible to some cores before others (before committing to cache), but every object has a mod order.

The whole point of memory reordering is that things don't necessarily happen in program order, so putting things on a timeline marked in clock cycles or nanoseconds isn't always possible.  RMWs and stores are linearizable (on a per-object basis, the mod order), loads in general aren't.  In hardware terms, they can take execute (a value from cache or store-forwarding) earlier than other loads nearby in program order.  In the C++ formalism, there's no notion of time, just ordering relative to other ops, so no way to define what "the latest" is.  A good implementation (hardware) gives low latency

@xmh0511: related: the "latest value" section of my answer on Is a memory barrier required to read a value that is atomically modified? , and Does hardware memory barrier make visibility of atomic operations faster in addition to providing necessary guarantees?

@PeterCordes and HolyBlackCat, For this question, the standard does have the intended meaning as said in the question, see https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/608#issuecomment-2337287962

@xmh0511 A random guy telling you "you're right" without any additional explanation or quotes from the standard doesn't mean you're actually right.

@HolyBlackCat A random guy He is the chair of CWG of C++.

@xmh0511 Yes, even if the guy is the CWG chair. :P

The text of your question doesn't match its title. The title mentions "read-modify-write operations," but in your question itself, you only use the following operations:

v.load() (read but not write)
v.store(1) (write but not read)
v.exchange(2) (read, then write)

A "read-modify-write operation" would be like compare_exchange_strong, or fetch_add (i.e. +=) — something that reads the atomic's old value, computes a new value based on ("modifying") that old value, and then writes the new value.
All atomic operations, including compare_exchange_strong and fetch_add, happen atomically, which means there's no way for any other thread to sneak a modification in between the read and the write. In other words, atomic operations are atomic. This is not the case for operations that are "non-atomic" — i.e., composed of smaller operations. For example:
int i = v.exchange(2);
  // A: Set v to 2 and load its
  // immediately previous value into i.
  // This is one atomic operation.

int i = v.load();
v.store(2);
  // B: Load v's value into i,
  // *then* set v to 2.
  // This is two atomic operations.

Suppose v is initially zero, and some other thread is doing int j = v.exchange(3) at the same time that we're executing one of the snippets above. Then it's possible for the second snippet to observe i=0 and j=0; whereas the first snippet can only ever observe either i=0 and j=2, or i=3 and j=0.
Does that help?

https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics#types.operations-19 exchange is RMW operation

Sure, in the context of defining a release sequence ( https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-5 ) — but you don't seem to be asking about that. Step 1 is just to understand what C++ means by "atomic"; and then, I claim, there is no Step 2 needed. :)
